# How to run/install Adobe's Illustrator cs6 and Photoshop and Flash and InDesign on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, windows

Okay, let me begin by saying that **I love the Ubuntu experience**. It's so amazing.

On the other hand, I am a graphic design professional and animation enthusiast.

**PROBLEM!** I cant install my favorite programs on Ubuntu, except for creating a virtual machine, the install either MAC OS-X or Windows. I want to ditch these commercial software completely, so **please** for the benefit of most Graphic Designers and Animation Crazies like myself, and again I plead with you, help us out with a good solution on how to go about it, or maybe even **develop a translation tool** that helps these programs run seamless in the Ubuntu environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you plead with us? People here are mostly users, not developers working for Adobe. Have you tried contacting Adobe instead?

Comment: Have you tried to search for alternatives? Do you have to work *exactly* with these programs?

Comment: Although Linux and especially Ubuntu has come a long way in terms of user experience refinements and support for plethora of programs.. there is still some way to go. Graphic designing is one of them. I maintain a dual boot primarily for Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop & Office. I can try and use virtual box but currently I don't have much memory in my 5 year old laptop to spare for the host OS and the virtual machine.

Answer (score 8):

[Wine (Windows Compatibility layer)](http://www.winehq.org/) is a software that gives you the possibility to run Windows software in Linux and OSX.

This of course doesn't mean that *every* Windows software will work, specially those that require Windows features only available in, well... Windows.

According to Wine's app database:

- Adobe Illustrator CS6 is rated Silver, meaning it works but up to a certain degree of functionality. ([more info](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26011))
- Adobe Photoshop  CS6 is also rated Silver ([more info](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=256071))
- Flash Professionnal CS6 is rated Silver,  ([more info](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26404))
- Adobe InDesign CS6 is rated Bronze, meaning it runs but it's highly unstable, ([more info](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26506))

If you want to use the Open Source alternatives to these softwares:

- Inkscape, is a free Vector drawing program to install it: `sudo apt-get install inkscape`
- GIMP, Pinta are free alternatives to Raster graphics editing software such as Photoshop to install any of them: `sudo apt-get install gimp`or `sudo apt-get install pinta`
- Synfig Studio is an animation software resembling Flash to install it [download it from their site and select the corresponding DEB file](http://www.synfig.org/cms/en/download/stable).
- Scribus is a DPT, a Desktop Publishing Tool much like InDesign to install it: `sudo apt-get install scribus`

Answer (score 3):

Nigel: You can try `Virtual Box` (or `VMWare`). You create a `Virtual Machine` and you can install NEARLY any operating system you want. The problem is, that you won't see `Windows` when you boot up. You will have to run `Ubuntu` and from there you will have to start the `Virtual Machine`.

I use `Virtual Box` in my job and have seven virtual machines. Two for our proprietary system, four with `Debian` and one with `Ubuntu` and they can communicate with each other via internal network.

Comment: I recommend this approach.

Comment: Yeah... I too recommend this approach if you system is 64-bit and has at least 8 GB of memory.

Comment: I'd go for 16GB of memory. I hit the 8GB mark quite easily on Windows with IntelliJ open and a browser full of tabs. On Ubuntu I guess you have a little more room as I read it uses around 1GB for idle OS with GUI and I guess there are fewer services loaded in the background.

Some wet finger work here: Ubuntu 1GB RAM, Windows in VM 2GB RAM, Photoshop + Bridge in VM 1GB RAM, browser with 5 tabs 1GB RAM, IntelliJ 1+GB RAM... Memory isn't that expensive anymore and I would not save money on that.