# How I Install Adobe Audition CS6 to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, adobe

How do I install Adobe Audition on Ubuntu?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228544/how-to-run-install-adobes-illustrator-cs6-and-photoshop-and-flash-and-indesign/228546#228546

Answer (score 3):

@Hasiya Rulzz I have to bring to your notice that you might not be able to run any product from the Adobe Creative Suite 6 natively into linux. Even to do that you might need application like **WINE** and as J Moore pointed, you can see some serious issue's running Adobe Creative Suite 6 on Linux using WINE.

What I can suggest is, you have two options:

1. You can try installing a Virtual Machine for Windows and try installing Adobe Creative Suite 6 there to work on, that should not be an issue.
2. If you are not just specific to Adobe Creative Suite 6 and can install any alternative cross-platform audio editor then I would suggest you to try [Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/audacity/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't; it appears to be broken in Wine: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25911